# Automatic Speech Recognition In Code Switching

Tags: python, nlp, multilingual, transformer-model, automatic-speech-recognition

I'm starting new project, this project should take two or more languages in the same audio as an input and outputs the speech in one language transcript. any thoughts how I can achieve this project

I tried wav2vec ,Nivida Nemo and deepspeech but no luck.

Comment: I'd probably try to classify the audio over smaller windows (maybe segregated by silence?) and then translate it.